# Best Way to Connect 3 Computers to Peripherals

Tags: multiple-monitors, usb-3, kvm-switch

I'm trying to find my best, low-latency option for connecting three computers. Generally, this wouldn't be an issue, but I see no way to do what I'm looking to do without having to plug/unplug cords each time I switch computers.

I have three computers:

1. Tower - In process of building. Dual(Maybe triple?)-Boot system
2. Work Laptop with Dock - MacBook Pro
3. Personal Laptop (may buy dock or may just use "dangling" cords) - Windows laptop

What I'd like is to be able to just dock the laptops and then switch between the three without having to plug/unplug cords. I've looked at KVM switches, but it seems nothing fits the bill in a single device.

Requirements

1. USB 3.0 support (will be using a powered 7-port hub, but need to be able to plug this hub in 3.0)
2. Dual monitor high-def setup (DVI or HDMI will be fine)
3. Keyboard/Mouse will be usb

I'm more a software developer than a hardware guy, so I would greatly appreciate some help/direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I seem to remember seeing some KVMs with more than two position that include USB.  Do a further search them.

Comment: @cliff2310 Thanks. I have looked at KVMs but cannot find any that handle USB 3.0, Dual HD monitors, and are at least 3-port. I have done some research and they don't seem to exist.

Comment: @sunk818 The MAC laptop supports two lightening ports out for a triple monitor setup (I would be using the USB 3.0 HUB, but still shouldn't be an issue), and I have a friend who is pushing three monitors using the same laptop without issue. Not sure about the Windows laptop's capabilities, but I'm not too concerned about that one. The tower and the MAC would suffice if I had to drop support for the Windows laptop.

Comment: @sunk818 I do require the 3.0. I'm not worried about the personal dock. It's an after-thought, but I do want the 3-port functionality. I'm planning on upgrading my personal laptop soon anyhow, so I can buy to match my setup. I'm open to USB 3.0 to HDMI monitor setup as well if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17308/discussion-between-sunk818-and-steventnorris).

Answer (score 0):

My previous setup required me to unplug my keyboard, mouse, and video and hook it up to the work laptop. It was a hassle to unplug, replug, and then put everything back after I was done. My solution was to purchase a work laptop and dock for personal use. Whenever I bring home work now, I just swap out the laptops. My dual video setup with keyboard and mouse remain undisturbed. I bought my setup from a used computer sale at work, so it cost me around $400 for an old Dell E6420 and dock.

For you, it may be a little harder as MacBook Pros have higher resale value. Still, I suggest you think about buying a high end MacBook Pro that will replace your tower and personal laptop. The advantage is you can keep your home setup exactly as it is and only swap out the laptop when you bring work home. I have developer friends that travel all over the country with a MacBook Pro. They use it to demo enterprise application that require 8GB of memory for Windows Server OS, application server, and database. They run all sorts of virtual machines (VMs) and there's plenty of power in a MacBook Pro to accommodate those requirements.

If you're MacBook Pro for work is sufficient, then get the same specs for personal use. If you get a MacBook Pro with different specs, you will be frustrated that one is too fast or too slow. You mitigate by purchasing a MacBook Pro with the same specs at work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, the tower is a necessity. I'm building it specifically as a gaming tower, and the MAC is work issued, so I have to use it for the work I do as it is set up for that environment (security necessities). I can't use a dock alone to switch out the laptops. I'd need some sort of system set up that can handle three (or at least two) separate machines.

Comment: Assuming your peripherals work on both Windows and Mac, and if USB 2.0 is OK, and DVI is okay, you can look at the [AdderView 4 Pro](http://www.adder.com/products/adderview-4-pro-dvi-multiscreen#specification). If you can accept USB 2.0 and just control two computers, then [IOGear makes a $470 one](http://www.iogear.com/product/GCS1642/). I couldn't find pricing on the ADDERView. I suggest you are sitting down when you ask about the price over the phone.

Comment: The USB 3.0 is a must for me unfortunately.